# Jarvis Widget inside a VueJS Component

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2, smartadmin

I am working on a **Laravel 5.7** application, that has a view with a **Jarvis Widget** [http://data.edwardsaquifer.org/widgets.php] inside of a **VueJS** component. However, I can't seem to get the Jarvis widget to function while wrapped within the **Vue Component**.

I have narrowed the issue down to the widget being wrapped inside of the Vue instance element.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#prospectsApp'
});
```

When the **jarvis widget** is wrapped inside of the **Vue** element instance **(#prospectsApp)**, is breaks all functionality of the widget.

```
<div id="prospectsApp">
    <section id="widget-grid">
        <div class="row">
            <article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 sortable-grid ui-sortable">
                <div class="jarviswidget jarviswidget-sortable" id="wid-id-0" role="widget">
                    <header class="ui-sortable-handle">
                        <div class="widget-header"> 
                            HEADER
                        </div>
                    </header>

                    <!-- widget div-->
                    <div role="content">
                        <!-- widget content -->
                        <div class="widget-body">
                            CONTENT
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

However when I move the element instance inside of the widget content, the functionality works again...

```
<section id="widget-grid">
    <div class="row">
        <article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 sortable-grid ui-sortable">
            <div class="jarviswidget jarviswidget-sortable" id="wid-id-0" role="widget">
                <header class="ui-sortable-handle">
                    <div class="widget-header"> 
                        HEADER
                    </div>
                </header>

                <!-- widget div-->
                <div role="content">
                    <!-- widget content -->
                    <div class="widget-body">
                        <div id="prospectsApp">
                            CONTENT
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Do I need to pass something into the Vue instance in order to keep the functionality of the widget intact?**

Comment: Please elaborate on `However I can't seem to get the Jarvis widget to function`. Do you mean they don't load whatsoever.. the interactivity isn't working or.. ?

Comment: The widget loads properly. However all functionality of the Jarvis widget is broken when wrapped with the Vue JS instance. (Minimize button, maximize button, etc)

Comment: Check out this article: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/

Comment: @McWayWeb your code is huge. Please edit it so as to present only the smallest amount of code required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @NinoFiliu I narrowed down the problem and updated the source code in my example.